# configure log4cplus to log to custom file at runtime

Tags: c++11, log4cplus, log4cpp

I am using configuration file to initialize log4cplus module. We use the below command in configuration file to specify the log file name to be generated.

*log4cplus.appender.log1.File=TestFile.log*

I want this TestFile.log to be generated at run time. I used setProperty function to change log file name at run time but didn't get the desired result.

In code -

*log4cplus::helpers::Properties props;
props.setProperty(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("File"), LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("TestFile.log"));*

In configuration file -

*log4cplus.appender.afile2.File=${File}*

But this will generate log file as "${File}" instead of "TestFile.log".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following line in your command.

```
log4cplus::helpers::Properties props("TextConfiguration.txt");
    props.setProperty(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("log4cplus.appender.afile2.File"), LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("TestFile.log"));
PropertyConfigurator conf(props);
conf.configure();
```

No need to change in configuration file.

Comment: What's the PropertyConfigurator? Thanks.